# ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 1) vs (None, 10000)) when trying to classify IMDB reviews

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, logits

I'm trying to classify IMDB movie reviews with binary classification using Keras. The following is the code I used.

```py
from keras import models
from keras import layers

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(16,activation="relu",input_shape=(10000,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(16,activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.Dense(1,activation="sigmoid"))

model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop",loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["acc"])

history = model.fit(partial_x_train,partial_y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=512, validation_data = (x_val, y_val))
```

shapes of each input tensors are as follows.

```
print(partial_x_train.shape) --> (15000, 10000)
print(partial_y_train.shape)--> (15000, 10000)
print(x_val.shape) --> (10000, 10000)
print(y_val.shape) --> (10000, 10000)
```

But on executing the above program, I get the following error.

```js
ValueError: in user code:
ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 1) vs (None, 10000))
```

I searched  through a lot of SO questions, but couldn't understand what I have done wrong. Can someone help me to avoid this error and make the model compiled?

Comment: you have 10000 targets while your network is producing only 1... set Dense(10000 , activation="sigmoid") as your last layer

Answer (score 1):

As stated `ValueError`, you're trying to compute the loss of between shape `((None, 1)` vs `(None, 10000))`. It would be clear if you posted or refer the training set of IMDB. Try with in-built IMDB data set from `keras`.

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

max_features = 20000  # Only consider the top 20k words
maxlen = 200  # Only consider the first 200 words of each movie review

(x_train, y_train), (x_val, y_val) = keras.datasets.imdb.load_data(
    num_words=max_features
)

print(len(x_train), "Training sequences")
print(len(x_val), "Validation sequences")

x_train = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=maxlen)
x_val = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(x_val, maxlen=maxlen)

x_train.shape, y_train.shape
# ((25000, 200), (25000,))
```

According to your model

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(16,activation="relu",input_shape=(maxlen,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(16,activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.Dense(1,activation="sigmoid"))

model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop",loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["acc"])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=2, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

```
Epoch 1/2
782/782 [==============================] - 5s 4ms/step - loss: 164.2350 - acc: 0.5018 - val_loss: 1.0527 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 2/2
782/782 [==============================] - 3s 4ms/step - loss: 1.0677 - acc: 0.4978 - val_loss: 0.7446 - val_acc: 0.5000
```